# How to check a table from arrays in js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table that consists of an array of arrays.
I need to check the value of each cell, then I can't figure out how to do this.
I will be grateful for your help.

Below I am taking a line from a file

```
export function parseCsvToRowsAndColumn(csvText, csvColumnDelimiter = '\t') {
    const rows = csvText.split('\n');
    if (!rows || rows.length === 0) {
        return [];
    }
    return rows.map(row => row.split(csvColumnDelimiter));
}
```

Here's my rendering table by lines

```
rows.map((row, rowIdx) => (
    <tr className={tableRowClassName} key={typeof(rowKey) === 'function' ? rowKey(row, rowIdx) : rowIdx}>
       {
         row.map && row.map((column, colIdx) => (
            <td className={tableColumnClassName}
                key={typeof(rowKey) === 'function' ? colKey(row, colIdx, rowIdx) : column[colKey]}>
                {typeof renderCell === "function" ? renderCell(column, colIdx, rowIdx) : column}
            </td>
          ))
        }
    </tr>
  ))
```

And then I don't understand how to check, for example, that the phone has at least 8 digits

Comment: You say "how to check [...] that the phone has at least 8 digits" but I don't understand how a phone comes into the question. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to check the value of each cell.

```
export function parseCsvToRowsAndColumn(csvText, csvColumnDelimiter = '\t') {
    const rows = csvText.split('\n');
    if (!rows || rows.length === 0) {
        return [];
    }

    return rows.map((row) => {
        const myCells = row.split(csvColumnDelimiter).map((cell) => {
            /// verify here, and don't forget to return
            myVerificationFunction(cell);
            return cell;
        });
        return myCells;
    });
}
```

---

> And then I don't understand how to check, for example, that the phone has at least 8 digits

You need a regEx for that

```
const hasAtLest8Digits = !!myvalue.replace(/[\t -\.]/g, '').match(/^[0-9]{8,}$/);
```

Match numbers from 0 to 9 `[0-9]` at least 8 times `{8,}`, the replace removes tabs, spaces, dots and -

Comment: In this case, I check every cell, but I need to check the entire column

Comment: the entire column is each nth cell of any row. myCells[0] in the map loop is each first element of the row, wich stacked together become a column, myCells[1] = second column and so on